# Excel row to column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any option that contains in a row.

For example ie.

```
A1-B-C1-D1-I1
```

I want this containt in a a column

Like this one

`A1-A2-A3-A4-A5-A6` to `A10`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very simple, please do the following:

1. Copy The data
2. Select the range you wish to paste into
3. Select Paste-Special: Transpose